# inline assembler in gives c2400 in vs 2015

Tags: c++

try to implement a basic operating system but this asm stuff is messing with my head i am using vs2015

the code that gives error

```
inline cpu_flags DisableInterrupts()

{
cpu_flags fl;


_asm volatile ("pushfl; popl %0; cli" : "=g" (fl));


return fl;
}
```

it gives error like this

Error    C2400   inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'data type'

after removing volatile also no luck

```
inline cpu_flags DisableInterrupts()
 {



 cpu_flags fl;


_asm ("pushfl; popl %0; cli" : "=g" (fl));


return fl;`
}
```

it gives

Error   C2400   inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different compilers in the world, and they all work a bit differently.

The syntax you are using in your question comes from [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) made by gnu.

However, you say you are trying to use it with Visual Studio which is made by Microsoft.  Visual Studio uses a very different syntax for inline asm than gcc.

I'm not going to try to teach you everything about Visual Studio's inline asm.  See their [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx).

Comment: thanks man,i am working on the visual studio version of my code and that link helped to.

Answer (score 1):

That's AT&T syntax used by gcc.

Visual Studio uses Intel syntax for its inline assembler. However, there is also a built in [_disable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y14401ab.aspx) function that doesn't require any assembler code.

Also not the remarks about the limited use of this function:

> This function is only available in kernel mode. If used in user mode, a Privileged Instruction exception is thrown at run time.

Comment: ok,what about the syntax thing you said is there way to change it to the intel syntax so that my visual studio can understand

Comment: Well, yes it would be just `__asm cli` but have no advantage over `_disable()`.

Comment: ok._disable() worked just fine but it doesn't  take any arguments so how can handle the rest of code like push and pop.